# CSS min() function isn't working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, min

I have a issue with css function "min" in Firefox to calculate an absolute position top of a tag a in a div

This is my code

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #c00;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

div.small {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: min(100px, 50%);
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">+</a>
</div>
<div class="small">
  <a href="#">+</a>
</div>
```

I share with you a JSFiddle where to show you the scenario
https://jsfiddle.net/okdsf8wh/1/

It seems to work fine with Chrome but not in Firefox.
The **min** css function should be supported by Firefox

Can somebody help me?
Thanks a lot.

Diego

Comment: it works fine on my Firefox

Comment: I see no difference between the two in a current Chrome and Firefox either.